# MongoDB How to get distinct list of sub-documents where the sub-documents' attribute is equal to some value?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
db.test.insert( 
    {
        'name': 'outer',
        'foos': [
            {
                'name': 'a',
                'type': 'bar',
            },
            {
                'name': 'a',
                'type': 'bar',
            },
            {
                'name': 'z',
                'type': 'baz',
            },
            {
                'name': 'z',
                'type': 'baz',
            },
        ]
    }
)
```

How can I obtain a distinct list of `foos` where `foo.type` is equal to `bar`?

I want to find:

```
[
    {
        'name': 'a',
        'type': 'bar'
    }
]
```

The following does not work but instead returns a distinct value for all of the foos.

```
db.test.distinct('foos', {'foos.type': 'bar'})
```

Comment: How about using `$aggregate` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Oops! A bit of misunderstanding of the function here. Here's what it returns and I'll explain why:

```js
[
        {
                "name" : "a",
                "type" : "bar"
        },
        {
                "name" : "z",
                "type" : "baz"
        }
]
```

So the other entry there is "type" equal to "baz", and both are now "distinct", but you missed what you really asked.

You did ask for distinct "foos", which is right. But you also only asked to get that from the "documents" that had an array entry with "type" equal to "bar". This does not "filter" the content to only those array entries, hence why you get the other result.

So you need to "filter" the content before obtaining the "distinct" values. You can only really do that with the `.aggregate()` method. And [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) is the best method here:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    // Match documents
    { "$match": { "foos.type": "bar" } },

    // Pre-filter the array
    { "$project": {
        "foos": {
            "$filter": {
                "input": "$foos",
                "as": "el",
                "cond": {
                    "$eq": [ "$$el.type", "bar" ]
                }
            }
        }
     }},

     // Unwind the array
     { "$unwind": "$foos" },

     // Group distinct
     { "$group": {
         "_id": "$foos"
     }}
])
```

Or in older than MongoDB 3.2, but version 2.6 and above you can alternately use [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) with [`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/):

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    // Match documents
    { "$match": { "foos.type": "bar" } },

    // Pre-filter the array
    { "$project": {
        "foos": {
            "$setDifference": [
                { "$map": {
                    "input": "$foos",
                    "as": "el",
                    "in": {
                        "$cond": [
                            { "$eq": [ "$$el.type", "bar" ] },
                            "$$el",
                            false
                        ]
                    }
                }}
            ]
        }
     }},

     // Unwind the array
     { "$unwind": "$foos" },

     // Group distinct
     { "$group": {
         "_id": "$foos"
     }}
])
```

That does the same thing, with `$map` processing each array element and returning either the mactched element or `false` and `$setDiffernce` removing the `false` ones:

And finally in anything older than 2.6:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    // Match documents
    { "$match": { "foos.type": "bar" } },

     // Unwind the array
     { "$unwind": "$foos" },

     // Filter the denormalized array
     { "$match": { "foos.type": "bar" } },

     // Group distinct
     { "$group": {
         "_id": "$foos"
     }}
])
```

The general principle is to only leave the array entries behind that match "type" equal to "bar", and ideal to "pre-filter" the array before using [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to reduce the work that needs to be processed, as filtering out afterwards would essentially create a new document for every array entry, whether it is a match or not.

At any rate, at some point you need to "de-normalize" the array entries with `$unwind` and then [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) back with "foos" ( sub-document) as the primary key value.

It's not a plain "array" as `.distinct()` delivers, but is basically how you just "weed out" the array entries you don't want to consider.

That's the thing to remember, as normal query operations do not "filter" array elements, then similarly the query input to `.distinct()` also does not do this, where removing those elements from consideration is what you intend to do.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was able to figure out your third example on my own (after 1 hour :)) From the three examples you provided, the third looks the most friendly. Does your ordering imply that the use of `unwind` is not as good as `filter` ?

Comment: @MatthewMoisen All exaples use `$unwind` since it would be necessary to obtain the "distinct" keys out of the arrays. The difference being if the only entries you want are removed from the arrays "before" you `$unwind` or "after". Naturally removing them "before" places less load on the overall processing, i.e *"less document expansion total in the overall pipeline"*. So that uses less memory and is most desirable.